# Verify input email address is exist or not in React.js or Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Is there any package or any other way to verify the entered email address is exist or not. SendGrid will send whatever email address you are passing but it is not telling the input email address is exists or not.

Please let me know if there is an way to verify it in React.js or Node.js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no way to guarantee that an email address is valid just from the address, no. As long as the domain exists and has an A or MX record then the domain part is potentially valid; you could try connecting to port 25 on one of those IP addresses to verify that there is a mail server there, but there's no way to be sure that the part before the @ will be accepted by the mail server without actually trying to send an email. Which is why sites send 'click here to confirm your address' emails I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use third party API's for that.
See: https://geekflare.com/email-verification-api/

Answer (score 1):

npm install deep-email-validator

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-email-validator

This dependency is going to take care of all the heavy lifting for us.It carries out the following tests:

- Validates the email regex
- Checks for common typos
- Determines if an email was generated by disposable email service.
- Checks for MX records on the DNS server.
- Determines if the SMTP server is running.
- Validates the existence of the mailbox on the SMTP server.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31488326)